# How to set browser window size larger than the screen resolution in Windows XP?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, windows-xp, screen-size

I would like to set browser size (mainly width) larger than the screen resolution in Windows XP. It looks like there is no easy way of dragging the browser window and resizing it. It resizes to maximum width and height of the actual screen, but no larger.

I need to check and test some webpages on large screens, but I have only a small notebook of my own. Is there a way how to accomplish a larger browser window? Preferrably in Chrome, but any browser in Windows will do.

Answer (score 10):

This problem can be solved in two ways: -

### 1. Universal browser solution

1. Create a dummy html page
2. Add an iframe to its body with the width and height attributes set to the desired dimension
3. Set the iframe's src attribute to the page you want to test

---

### 2. Individual browser's developer tools

### **Chrome**

1. Open the developer tools using Ctrl + Shift + i
2. Click the second button top left that looks like a mobile phone
3. Drag the width to the desired width and refresh the page (F5)

---

### **Internet Explorer**

1. Press F12
2. Go to the emulation tab
3. Change the resolution dropdown to the desired resolution
4. Reduce the height of the developer tools bar until the horizontal scrollbars appear

---

### **Firefox**

1. Open the developer tools using Ctrl + Shift + i
2. Press the third icon in the icons on the top right of the developer tools called "Responsive Design Mode"
3. Choose the resolution in the top left dropdown selector on the top left of the webpage viewport.

Comment: Chrome can at most set the size to 9999x9999. How to set beyond this value? I have difficulty in setting up an iframe as I know little to html

Answer (score 4):

I am testing another resolution by zoom out - every browser supports ctrl + and ctrl -

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. First 'restore' (i.e. unmaximize) the window. Then you can simply adjust the width and height of the browser by using the edges of that particular window as you like. 
This applies to any browser and application windows including google-chrome.

It seems like this doesn't work for every user. There's a tool called uuspy to do this as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123410/can-a-window-be-resized-past-the-screen-size-offscreen). I haven't try on how to do this. But, since the ui of uuspy looks not that user-friendly here's quick tip.
Open uuspy. 
There, in the main window, you'll see a search box. Type the first few letters of the current 'title' of the browser there (like 'test - Google Search'), and then click `refresh`.
It'll show a list of windows and child-windows of processes containing the searched partial title in the title-bar.
Click on the relevant one (the root/parent is the one most likely.) Then, click `GetInfo`.
There's two text panes there. On the left pane, there's WS_THICKFRAME. unselect it and then click `setStyle`. 
That will freeze the resizing. I think you'll have to read the original SO answer to know exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: Yes, but this way browser window can be resized only up to screen resolution size, but no higher. And I need make browser window larger than actual screen width.

Comment: Well, you CAN make browser window larger than actual screen width by this way. Did you try it? Remember, you have to restore the window first. You can't change the size if the window is maximized.

Comment: thats exactly what I am trying, but system doesn't let me make it larger.. Even if I drag window little out of screen and then resize it by click-and-drag by side it doesn't resize beyond the screen width

Comment: OP is right, I cannot resize the window beyond the screen size, even if it is partially outside the screen (win7).

Comment: I see. [This page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123410/can-a-window-be-resized-past-the-screen-size-offscreen) suggests that this works for some, and not for others. I don't remember setting a specific configuration though.  
It suggests to use uuSpy to change the THICKFRAME setting to make this possible. (I haven't tried it)

Comment: Ok, uuSpy seems to be the right tool, however it is very complex. Can you edit your answer or make a new one with simple tutorial how to set browser window size in uuSpy ?

Answer (score 1):

simple! "restore" the window to any size, drag the window so that bottom/left corner is off-screen, then resize using top and right sides to make the window ever bigger. if you need it even bigger, just drag the window again so that bottom/left corner is even further off screen.

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted, on my Windows 8 machine such a window will not be possible to resize wider than the width of the screen, regardless of how much I move parts of it off-screen... seems to be a Windows limitation?

Comment: @OskarDuveborn xp and windows 7+ handle window resizing differently

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resize the Chrome window using [ScreenSpace from dandeware.com](http://www.dandeware.com/products/) (no affiliation). There's a free lite version as well as a paid version.

After you install Screenspace, select the Chrome window and press Ctrl-Alt-R. The software then shows a virtual window and lets you resize the Chrome window in any direction beyond the virtual window. Click on the green checkmark and the Chrome window will have the same size on your physical screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can change zoom of the browser or do something like this:

```
var desiredWidth = 1368;
document.querySelector('html').style.width = desiredWidth+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox [Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode)

```
Menu -> Developer -> Responsive Design Mode (Ctrl-Shift-M)
```

gives you a drop-down to select the window size.

[image: responsive design of this page set to 1920x1080]

<sub>copy of answer to https://superuser.com/questions/1263519/how-to-create-a-1280x800-screenshot-of-a-chrome-browser-viewport/1263523</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Here's another solution.
Under Linux you can freely resize the windows without any hindrance. It also has Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome, and are almost equal in functionality to the Windows versions more or less. So, my suggestion is try this with a Linux flavor such as Ubuntu or Linux Mint. May be you can try this via the LiveCD as well. That way, you don't have to worry about installing a new OS! I can help with that if you need.

And, I found this handy [bookmarklet](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/firefox-resize-bookmarklet-now-with-re-positioning/) that resizes the browser to standard screen sizes such as 800x600 etc.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a dual moniter setup and set the resolution higher on one, then you can drag the size of the window on the smaller screen to the size of the larger so it will get bigger than the smaller screen -this is haw i do it with windows 7

Comment: The op clearly states that he "he only has a small notebook" screen.