# Wxpython, Force window size to be bigger than screen size

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

How do I make WXPython disregard monitor sizes, when it resizes?

I want to make a really large window, so I can get a bitmap of all elements within the window. This program is not meant to be interactive in any way. I am using wxpython to set up a poster, using sizers, pictures and text, and then getting a bitmap via the DC.

All I found on this issue was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123410/can-a-window-be-resized-past-the-screen-size-offscreen), asking about the same problem, using the WinAPI.