# Resizing another threads window with MFC above screen size

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, resize, window

I use the handle of a window from another process to resize and reposition it from an MFC based app. The handle comes from a window search for Title.

Repositioning works fine, resizing too - if not larger then the screen resolution.

But that's the problem - I want it to be bigger then the actual screen.

Even if set partially outside the visible screen area with negative coordinates in SetWindowPos it does not scale above the values returned by GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) and GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: [Can a window be resized past the screen size/offscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123410/can-a-window-be-resized-past-the-screen-size-offscreen)

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137828/6538170 but since it's another processes window I don't have code access to I can't apply that solution.

Comment: Perhaps you can if you inject a [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) into that process.